# How to use multiple pages in Phonegap?

Tags: android, html, cordova, phonegap-build

I have checked out the forum a lot and there are many similar question to this, but none have the answer what I am looking for so hope someone can help me!

I am building an app with phonegap and it have previously worked fine. Now it was time for an update of just some text and images in it, but also decided to get the newest version of everything.

I can launch my app on android just fine, but as soon as I click on a link to another page (internal) I get the following error:
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(file:///android_asset/www/html/feriehus.html)

It used to work with the following code in the index.html, but does not anymore...does anybody know why?

```
<li><a href="html/feriehus.html"><img src="img\feriehus.png" width="40"></a></li>
```

Kind regards, Kiam

Edit: Added images to show their location:

[the root of www folder where index.html is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5HMuV.png)

[The location of ferirhus.html is located](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iW44r.png)

Comment: It is not possible to answer this question with the information you have given. You seem to have replaced some files - where are they? Does the file `feriehus.html` exist somewhere?

Comment: If your current file and feriehus.html file both are in same folder than don't use `html/` in href or check if which files are in root directory or into www/html/ directory will solve your problem.

Comment: The index.html file, where this is from is in the root of www.

In www is a folder called html, where the feriehus.html file is located

Comment: I made a quick test and if they are located in the same root space there is not issue, but as soon as I want to access a folder it can't find it...

Comment: change folder name from html to some other name

Comment: That seemed to do the trick! Thx, but do you know why that was an issue? Since it was not previously

Comment: Probably because html is a reserved name. I am posting it as an answer, mark it as correct so that it may help someone in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change folder name from **html** to some other name. Because **html** is a reserved word so it might be creating problem.